# How to generalize/simplify this annotation command?

Tags: tikz-pgf

To annotate my graphics I currently use the following commands

```
\def\foolabellu[#1][#2](#3){%
  % synopsis
  % \foolabellu[text][length](endpoint)
  \coordinate (breakpoint) at ($(#3)+(-0.5,-0.5)$);
  \coordinate (startpoint) at ($(breakpoint)+(-#2, 0)$);
  \draw (startpoint) -- node[anchor=south west, pos=0, inner sep=0pt, yshift=0.15em] {#1\strut}  (breakpoint) -- (#3);
}
\def\foolabelru[#1][#2](#3){%
  \coordinate (breakpoint) at ($(#3)+(+0.5,-0.5)$);
  \coordinate (startpoint) at ($(breakpoint)+(#2, 0)$);
  \draw[thin] (startpoint) -- node[anchor=south east, pos=0, inner sep=0pt, yshift=0.15em] {#1\strut}  (breakpoint) -- (#3);
}
\def\foolabelld[#1][#2](#3){%
  \coordinate (breakpoint) at ($(#3)+(-0.5,+0.5)$);
  \coordinate (startpoint) at ($(breakpoint)+(-#2, 0)$);
  \draw (startpoint) -- node[anchor=south west, pos=0, inner sep=0pt, yshift=0.15em] {#1\strut}  (breakpoint) -- (#3);
}
\newcommand\foolabelrd{}
\def\foolabelrd[#1][#2](#3){%
  \coordinate (breakpoint) at ($(#3)+(+0.5,+0.5)$);
  \coordinate (startpoint) at ($(breakpoint)+(#2, 0)$);
  \draw[thin] (startpoint) -- node[anchor=south east, pos=0, inner sep=0pt, yshift=0.15em] {#1\strut}  (breakpoint) -- (#3);
}
```

which called in this example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm] (rect) {};

  \foolabellu[\small left up][2.5](rect.south);
  \foolabelru[\small right up][2](rect.east);
  \foolabelld[\small left down][2.5](rect.west);
  \foolabelrd[\small right down][2](rect.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces this

[image]

In my opinion the use of four commands is pretty excessive and redundant but I cannot get my head around how to do it more generically for the text anchors. Moreover the way it is written now, it is not very flexible, for example I'd like to use the starting node for other things.

Is there a more canonical/TikZish way of implementing these annotations?

Comment: What parameters would you like to keep for those annotations? Because that will change how the command is built. For example: angle? Distance? Etc. The more parameters, the more complicated it gets. :)

Comment: Ideally, I'd just have the orientation (i.e. coming from left or right and going up or down). To keep things simple, the angle could be fixed and the length be deduced from the text itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution provides a single command `\annotate` with currently 5 arguments (I'm working on reducing them to 2 arguments only):

```
\annotate{ <node to annotate> }{ <top text> }{ <right> }{ <bottom> }{ <left> }
```

The annotation goes in a clockwise fashion, starting from the top, like this:

[image]

If one of the `text` arguments is left empty, nothing is drawn, but an invisible diagonal path is created to preserve some spacing.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\annotate[5]{%
    \foreach \nodanc/\anch/\text [
        count=\x starting from 0, 
        evaluate=\x as \ang using int(90*\x)
        ] in {%
        south west/north/{#2},
        south west/east/{#3},
        south east/south/{#4},
        south east/west/{#5}
    }{%
    \IfStrEq{\text}{}{%
        \path (#1.\anch) --++ ({45-\ang}:7mm);
    }{%
        \draw (#1.\anch) --++ ({45-\ang}:7mm) coordinate (a);
        \node[anchor=\nodanc, text width=2cm] (b) at (a) {\text};
        \draw (b.south west) -- (b.south east);
    }%
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm] (rect) {};

\annotate{rect}{a long long text here}{}{left down}{left up}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```